# Working part-time in Italy as a student, self-employed?

Tags: visa, student-visa, students

Buongiorno a tutti!

I am applying for a student visa upon acceptance into an accademia belle arte in Rome. I currently meet the requirements for tuition expenses and can prove the necessary monetary support for the upcoming academic season.

Is self-employment included in the 20-hours a week maximum for a student to participate in working to support themselves through school? I am a certified yoga instructor and also will be selling my artwork through galleries in the U.S. to help me pay for my continuing artistic education.

Any advice or experience with this situation is very much appreciated.

Una bella giornata,

Victoria